# How will HttpClient behave for multiple adresses when made static?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Thumbing through .NET documentation I stumbled upon **[HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2)** docs. It is advised there to create one, presumably static, instance of client for entire application like this (copied from docs in a link):

```
public class GoodController : ApiController  
{  
    // OK  
    private static readonly HttpClient HttpClient;  

    static GoodController()  
    {  
        HttpClient = new HttpClient();  
    }  
}
```

The reason for this in not to exhaust number of sockets available under heavy load.

However, let's assume that we use this HttpClient to send requests to different adressess using a wrapper class e.g:

```
public class HttpClientWrapper
{
    private static readonly HttpClient ClientInstance;

    static HttpClientWrapper()
    {
        ClientInstance = new HttpClient();
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Send(string address, HttpContent content)
    {
        return await ClientInstance.PostAsync(address, content);
    }
}
```

It is possible then that multiple requests to different adresses are made by the HttpClient, which is supposed to be a singleton (about what I am not sure in this example).

*Questions are :*

**1. How to correctly implement advices from docs to behave like in the second example (be able to send to different addresses without exhausting socket pool)?**

**2. How will HttpClient behave with concurrent multiple request to different addresses when it is static/singleton? Will it keep track of all the addresses or overwrite some setting internal to HttpClient (e.g `BaseAddress`) and mistake adresses (or throw exceptions)?**

Comment: "Will it keep track of all the addresses or overwrite some setting internal to HttpClient and mistake adresses" - this isn't clear: do you mean `BaseAddress`? The short answer is that you can't use `.BaseAddress` or `DefaultRequestHeaders` because they are properties of `HttpClient` and thus shared.

Comment: Just a note - using the same name as the underlying type is generally a bad idea as it makes the code less readable.

Comment: @John - I was not sure what were HttpClient internals when asking the question, but digging into documentation - I think that yes, `BaseAddress` is what I meant. @Tim - I will edit this in question for clarity

Comment: @GrayCat - Looks like the MS docs use the same (bad, IMO) naming convention.

Comment: @Tim - so I cant use `BaseAddress`, but what will happen when I PostAsync to two different URIs? Do they write to `BaseAddress` or use completely separate ... let's say caches for each request, thus preventing errors that could occur when using single instance to communicate in parallel with different addresses?